# Testing empty variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have a large number of variables in my script, and I want the script to error out if any one of the variables are empty.

I know I can:

```
if [[ -z "$var_1" ]] || [[ -z "$var_2" ]] || ... [[ -z "$var_n" ]]; then
  # failure message
fi
```

However, I cannot inform the user which variable was empty if I do it in this way. Is there an alternative approach to the above so that I can inform the user about the empty variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
foo=(var_1 var_2 var_n)

for bar in ${foo[*]}
do
  if [[ ! ${!bar} ]]
  then
    echo $bar is empty
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `${var:?var is empty or unset}` the first time you reference the variable.  If empty strings are acceptable and you only care if the variables are set, do `${var?var is unset}`.  Using `?` in the parameter expansion causes the shell to terminate and if the variable is (empty or) unset.